# .htaccess 301 redirect with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have converted my asp site to php recently. 
URLs remained the same, but obviously mysite.com/*/*.asp pages became mysite.com/*/*.php
I used this .htaccess entry to redirect (and it works perfectly):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ $1.php [R=301, L]
```

My problem is, that I **had** to change *some* of the old URLs, so the above rule doesn't function properly.
Is it possible to add additional rules to .htacces, that overwrite the above global rule?
Like

```
Redirect 301 /path/page.asp mysite.com/path/page_new.php
```

and if possible, where to put it?

Thank you.

Comment: See [301 redirect domain with exception](https://helponnet.com/2021/05/01/redirect-domain-with-exception/)

Answer (score 0):

Stick with mod_rewrite since you're already using it and not through mod_alias(Redirect) into the mix.

Just add the URL's you want redirect specifically `before` your catchall rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^specific\.asp$ /path/page_new.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^specific2\.asp$ /path/page_new2.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ $1.php [R=301, L]
```

Let me know how this works out.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when my site goes live soon.